# Locate the source of an rsync backup

Tags: rsync

I have an inherited server (foo) which I am told is receiving backups via rsync from various hosts (bar1, bar2, etc).

I'm looking to identify network information (hostname or ip address) for bar from information available on foo. Such that I can log into bar and disable any rsync backups. I am told that all data from bar systems is being backed up into /u on foo. /u appears to be populated with home directories.

I do not know when these backups from bar systems are run, or how long they may be running.

Comment: Please add more details to your question.  Is "foo" running a backup server, or is it a client of a different backup server? What do you mean by "find bar"? Do you want to know where it is physically? Do you want to know its IP address? Do you want to know where its backups live?  The more details, the better, so please be verbose.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on what's being backed up via rsync? I mean if `/etc/hostname` is backed up, that would tell you something......

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is identify at which time rsync is being run. You can do this with auditd

Put a watch on rsync executable on your server

```
which rsync
/usr/bin/rsync
auditctl -w /usr/bin/rsync -k rsync
```

Then you can periodically check if auditd logged any access like this

```
ausearch -i -k rsync
```

Once you know times when rsync runs - you can now identify which remote hosts use it.

Example:

See process tree and identify what rsync uses

```
pstree -p|grep -i rsync
        |-sshd(3861)-+-sshd(26209)---bash(26212)---rsync(27858)---rsync(27859)
```

And check which remote hosts are connected to PID 26209

```
netstat -anp|grep 26209
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      26209/sshd          
tcp        0      0 10.10.10.20:22              10.10.10.40:64740          ESTABLISHED 26209/sshd          
tcp        0      0 ::1:6010                    :::*                        LISTEN      26209/sshd
```

All this assumes that rsync actually takes some time, so you can execute those pstree and netstat commands. If rsync is very quick - there are other ways to do tracing, but it will be more heavy (systemtap is on my mind for this, but start from simple and if that doesn't work - we will discuss more complex solutions).